# How to override translate csv files in magento2

Tags: magento2, localisation

Suppose, I want to translate **Shop By** to **Shop** in my custom theme using translation file **en_US.csv**

What is the method or procedure to achieve it in **Magento2**?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to just override the **en_US.csv** file into your theme **i18n** folder.

```
app/design/frontend/{Vendorname}/{themename}/i18n/en_US.csv
```

Comment: This doesn't work with custom child theme of custom parent theme. For instance, if you create a custom theme FOO with blank theme as parent, and then BAR theme with FOO theme as parent, the csv of BAR will override the csv of FOO, inheritance will not work.

Comment: This is for only frontend, how to do this for admin and frontend both?

Comment: This is not working for a particular string. "Coupon code is not valid" which is present in module-quote. Any input?

Comment: @Rakesh, It's not working. Magento version: 2.3.2

Comment: @SejalShah - same issue 'Coupon code is not valid' is not translating. How to fix that?

Comment: Do I only the changes in this folder, or do I copy it all and then edit?

Answer (score 12):

Create a `en_US.csv` file in this path.

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/i18n/en_US.csv
```

Put your changes in this file.

Clear cache (`bin/magento cache:clean`) and check your changes.

Comment: Do I only the changes in this folder, or do I copy it all and then edit? If only changes, then this could be "extending" not "overriding" as the other answer suggested?