# Override magento 2 module Success message on "Save Config"

Tags: magento2, module

The default success message is 'You saved the configuration.' while hitting the 'Save Config' button in the Magento 2 Module. How to override with my customized message?

Answer (score 0):

You need to override

**magento\vendor\magento\module-config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Save.php**

`execute()` function http://webkul.com/blog/overriding-rewriting-classes-magento2/

**magento\vendor\magento\module-config\i18n\en_US.csv** You need to override if needed [How to override translate csv files in magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/147713/how-to-override-translate-csv-files-in-magento2)